# How to change align to left when top divs in the center

Tags: html, css

The parent div `.post_loader_inside` has many child `main_post` in the center. when I change my screen width the last `main_post`s are also going to the center! but I want to the other divs go to the left of the parent div without change the margin and width of my `main_post`s.

[image]

OR:
[image]

```css
:root {
        --post_loader: 100%;
        --main_post_width: 100px;
        --main_post_height: 100px;
        --inner_post_width: 100%;
        --inner_post_height: 100%;
        --main_post_radus: 8px;
    }



    section.post_loader {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: var(--post_loader);
        height: auto;
        background-color: #da02ff;
         padding: 20px;
    }

    section.post_loader div.post_loader_inside {
        height: auto;
        background-color: green;
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div.main_post {
        background-color: #0000ff;
        width: var(--main_post_width);
        height: var(--main_post_height);
        margin: 15px;
        position: relative;
        /* left: 50%;
        top: 50%; */
        display: inline-block;
        /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
        border-radius: var(--main_post_radus);
    }

    div.main_post div.inner_post {
        display: block;
        width: var(--inner_post_width);
        height: var(--inner_post_height);
        border-radius: var(--main_post_radus);
    }

    div.main_post div.inner_post_width div.post_part {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc();
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <section class="post_loader">
            <div class="post_loader_inside">
              <div class="main_post">
                    <div class="inner_post">
                        <div class="post_part spart_1"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_2"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_3"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_4"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_5"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main_post">
                    <div class="inner_post">
                        <div class="post_part spart_1"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_2"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_3"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_4"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_5"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main_post">
                    <div class="inner_post">
                        <div class="post_part spart_1"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_2"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_3"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_4"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_5"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main_post">
                    <div class="inner_post">
                        <div class="post_part spart_1"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_2"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_3"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_4"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_5"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main_post">
                    <div class="inner_post">
                        <div class="post_part spart_1"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_2"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_3"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_4"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_5"></div>
                        <div class="post_part part_6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS ...

```
    section.post_loader div.post_loader_inside {
        height: auto;
        background-color: green;
        width: 90%;
        /* text-align: center; */
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

... removing `text-align: center` will do the trick, though it has the undesirable side-effect of not centering the squares within their container.

What if you put `.post_loader_inside` inside another div, and center that?

Comment: Show me please..?

Comment: I'm talking about this ...
https://jsfiddle.net/designosis/e10tpkso/11/
... still in progress :)

Comment: The post div.main_post are not aligned into the center!

Answer (score 0):

```
section.post_loader div.post_loader_inside 
{
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center; /* Remove this */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 15px; /* Add this to compensate */
}
```

If your purpose is to make a grid layout, I highly recommend looking into CSS grid and Flex, they are very useful tools for this.

[CSS Grid tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

## Update:

OP requested a css grid solution:

- Static, always 3 boxes in a row
- Dynamic, fills automatically

## Static

```css
*, html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* If you want grid to be always 3 boxes in a row */
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 15px;
    row-gap: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6vh 6vw;
}


.container div{
    background: red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Dynamic

```css
*, html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* If you want grid to be dynamic: */
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    column-gap: 15px;
    row-gap: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 6vh 6vw;
}

.container div{
    background: red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The flex and grid are always change spaces between the divs I want to 15px of all spaces

Comment: @SchoolforDesign grid does not change spaces on their own. You simply need to use the `gap`-property and set it to 15px.

Comment: Yes @tacoshy is right, adding just `display: grid;`  or `display:flex;` is not enough. But if you follow the tutorial I gave you, you should find exactly how to solve your issue =)

I also updated the code, so if you decide that today is not the day for grid / flex, you can just copy it and replace the same from your css file.

Comment: add an answer with grid or flex for me please...

Comment: I added an example how you can achieve what you want using grid.